# Can I resubmit a manuscript that has been rewritten and professionally edited?

Tags: publishing, email, submitting-work

Three weeks ago, my manuscript was "accepted" by a publisher and a contract signed. I immediately notified every literary agency to which I'd sent a submission of the contract signing.

The manuscript was edited by the publishing company & returned to me with suggested changes. When I pushed back on a couple of the changes, the publisher terminated the contract citing personality differences while praising my manuscript. So, how do I approach those other literary agencies again? Would an email directly to the agent advising of the contract cancellation be appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you review the terminated contract to make sure there aren't any conditions or effects that would linger after contract termination.

After you do that, feel free to resubmit anywhere you like.  If it was one of the agencies you had previously sent a notice to, explaining that it had been accepted but not ultimately published would probably be a nice thing to do.